# KeyError coming up when trying to read from Excel file using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

so i have a small problem with my code. I am trying to get some data from an excel file using pandas but it is throwing a KeyError every time I give the column i want the data from. Here is the sample code i am using.

```
import pandas as pd
excel_1 = pd.read_excel(r'here comes the file path', 'Sheet1')
print (excel_1['V_peak'])
```

The weird thing about this is that it works with only one column, but not with the others. So as an example i'll use the picture below, if i use V_peak, then it works. If i use V_eff or Pressure end, then the error pops up.

[Excel column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdWU7.png)

**The error messages look like this**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "D:\untitled4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line
>   2656, in get_loc
>           return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>         File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>         File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>         File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>         File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>       KeyError: 'V_eff'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/untitled4/Test 2.py", line 7, in 
>           print (excel_1['V_eff'])
>
> File "D:\untitled4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in **getitem**
>           indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
>      File "D:\untitled4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line
>   2658, in get_loc
>           return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>       File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>         File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>         File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>         File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>       KeyError: 'V_eff'
>
> ```
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```